# A significant part of SQL Server process memory has been paged out

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, memory

Around 7:30pm every evening we receive the following message and the server experiences an outage of 2 minutes.

> A significant part of sql server process memory has been paged out. This may result in a performance degradation. Duration: 1868 seconds. Working set (KB): 2096696, committed (KB): 18715612, memory utilization: 11%.

The message appears in the log 4 times around a 5 minute period.

I have been investigating, and we do not have 'lock pages in memory' activated.
 Also, the `min server mem` is 0 (default) and `max server memory` set at around 26GB.

Nothing seems that unusual when looking at perfmon counters ie: Available MB, Free Pages, Page Life, Lazy Writes.

Its possible that there is memory pressure as a result of backing up our DBs around this time.

How can I better check what the problem is / rectify the situation?

Edit: Results of

```
select TOP 10 
    (sum(pages_kb)*128)/1024 as 'sizein_mb',
    type as 'clerkttype' 
from 
    sys.dm_os_memory_clerks 
group by 
    type 
order by 
    (sum(pages_kb)*128)/1024 desc

1903846  MEMORYCLERK_SQLBUFFERPOOL  
428635  CACHESTORE_SQLCP  
148648  CACHESTORE_OBJCP  
22371   MEMORYCLERK_SOSNODE  
16802   USERSTORE_SCHEMAMGR  
6834    OBJECTSTORE_LOCK_MANAGER  
5494    CACHESTORE_PHDR  
5246    MEMORYCLERK_SQLSTORENG  
4513    USERSTORE_DBMETADATA  
4168    MEMORYCLERK_SQLGENERAL
```

Comment: I don't know why DB backups would cause significant memory pressure. The transfer buffers are tiny.

Comment: Is this SQL Server running in a VM or on a physical machine?  Also, why is `lock pages in memory` not turned on?  Or are you planning to turn it on?

Comment: Have you tried querying [sys.dm_os_ring_buffers](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/918483) to see if sql server was experiencing memory pressure ? Are there any memory dumps created ? check - `sys.dm_server_memory_dumps`. Remember that LPM will protect only buffer pool.

Comment: No. Server is on 2 x 500GB SATA HDD

Comment: Theres around 9 files in `sys.dm_server_memory_dumps` totalling around 175mb. That's not an issue surely?

Comment: @AMorton1989 Can you check if they are when sql server logged the message ? How many databases are on the instance and how big they are ? We need more info to help you.

Comment: The most recent dump happened 9 days ago. At around the time mentioned 7:30pm. We did actually reboot the server the Friday before that weekend to refresh everything.

Comment: backups wont use buffer pool

Comment: Can you also run this query and add to question to see memory by clerks.  select (sum(pages_kb)*128)/1024 as 'sizein_mb',type as 'clerkttype'
from sys.dm_os_memory_clerks
group by type
order by (sum(pages_kb)*128)/1024 desc

Comment: Ok, Ill post the top 10 results above. It seems there is quite a lot of information in the SQLBufferpool

Comment: Is this an issue / Do you think I would need to manually perform Checkpoint operation and DBCC DropCleanBuffers to clear this out?

Comment: There are 16 databases on the server totalling around 93.5GB